# Scripts order issue in Unity 5 Networking

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

I just started to work with new unity networking system in Unity5. Today I found out a weird thing that I couldn't understand.

I make 2 new scripts and add "Debug.Log" into Start() and Update(), both of them, then disable the game object with 2 scripts added as components, once the game started, I enable the game object, check the console window, everything looks normal.

[image]

Then if I add NetworkManager game object and add "NetworkIdentity" to previous logging game object, start the game, host the game, the logging game object will be automatically enabled, then you will see this at console window.

[image]

It seems Start() and Update() functions are not according what they should be, did I misunderstanding any about Unity Networking??

[image]

---

Thanks for reminding, so I add "Awake()" into the test, then more weird things happened.
A gameobject with "NetworkIdentity" will call its "Awake" before StartHost() to enable the gameobject in Editor Mode, but once you make a build, "Awake" will be call after StartHost(). This leads me more confused. :(

Comment: try awake instead of start

Answer (score 0):

Each network identity gameobject become disable as scene start and then Automatically active by the scene manager as unity docs stated:

> All objects in the scene with a NetworkIdentity component will be
>   disabled when the scene is loaded; on both the client and the server.
>   Then, when the scene is fully loaded, NetworkServer.SpawnObjects() is
>   called to activate these networked scene objects. This will be done
>   automatically by the NetworkManager when the server scene finishes
>   loading - or can be called directly by user code([more](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSceneObjects.html)).

So according to my understanding, objects are enable one by one, so the order of log in your code is not weird(every object enable one by one and thier scripts start execute in the same order).

Comment: From Unity forum, they told me that it's a bug, and will be fixed in future

Comment: please refer it in to your answer and give answer here.

Comment: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/when-awake-will-be-call-for-game-object-with-networkidentity.441678/?_ga=1.173148641.3943044.1475111278

Comment: You might misunderstand my saying, the thing is the behavior of Awake() is inconsistent between Editor and Built player, this is something unacceptable, people have to be aware and code very carefully to avoid weird issue in game.

Comment: ok thanks but i am still looking for additive scene loading in network